# How can I force my android application run only with RTL layout directon?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, right-to-left

I want to have RTL-only layout. I don't want to have layouts that  depend on user cellphone's language . What should I add in my android manifest file to make my application RTL forcedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set this `android:supportsRtl="false"` in your application tag in manifest and design your layouts as a rtl layout. then it won't change the layouts base on the device direction

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Android doesn't support *only* RTL as the only flag is to state either RTL support or not.

You will just need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` and make your layouts only specific to RTL support.